# Will Self Sign Certificate work while publishing to chrome cast?

Tags: android, https, ssl-certificate, chromecast, ca

Developing a simple android application that will cast a URL (webpage) on bigger display.

For publishing "the receiver app must be served over SSL (HTTPS)". For that I have generated self-signed SSL Certificate and plan to use the same.

[URL for publish](https://basilapps.com/recipe/index1.html)

However, On trying to access the page from browser, it gives following warning:

> The site's security certificate is not trusted! You attempted to reach
>   basilapps.com, but the server presented a certificate issued by an
>   entity that is not trusted by your computer's operating system. This
>   may mean that the server has generated its own security credentials,
>   which Chrome cannot rely on for identity information, or an attacker
>   may be trying to intercept your communications.

**So my query is: 
(A) Will self-signed certificate will work fine during publishing?
(B) If not, then do I need to purchase SSL certificate from trusted authority?
(C) Are there freely available trusted certificates services available?**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self-signed certs do not work and yes, you need to get/use a trusted one form a known authority. If you can use App Engine, that works since it already has that. For development, either use http or use App Engine or even Google Drive (the last two support https).

Comment: for publishing can we use app engine or google drive ?

Comment: You can, there is no restriction on where you choose to host your receiver (as long as it has a valid cert). App Engine definitely can easily scale and is built to host applications but that is not Drive's main use case so if I were to host it somewhere, I would definitely not choose Drive as a long term hosting solution; it works great for development but I would go with App Engine for a production solution.